# I am not able to run lightgbm on Mac because of an OSerror: libomp.dylib' (no such file)

Tags: macos, lightgbm

I am not able to run lightbm on my MAC. I already tried all the solutions that I found but I can't get rid of the problem.

When I import lightgbm the following OSERROR appears:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 6>()
  4 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
  5 import time
----> 6 from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
  7 from xgboost import XGBClassifier
  8 print('make classification ...')

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/__init__.py:8, in <module>
  2 """LightGBM, Light Gradient Boosting Machine.
  3 
  4 Contributors: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/graphs/contributors.
  5 """
  6 from pathlib import Path
----> 8 from .basic import Booster, Dataset, Sequence, register_logger
  9 from .callback import early_stopping, log_evaluation, print_evaluation, record_evaluation, reset_parameter
 10 from .engine import CVBooster, cv, train

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py:110, in <module>
106         raise LightGBMError(lib.LGBM_GetLastError().decode('utf-8'))
107     return lib
--> 110 _LIB = _load_lib()
113 NUMERIC_TYPES = (int, float, bool)
116 def _safe_call(ret: int) -> None:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py:101, in _load_lib()
 99 if len(lib_path) == 0:
100     return None
--> 101 lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
102 lib.LGBM_GetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
103 callback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_char_p)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py:460, in LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary(self, name)
459 def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 460     return self._dlltype(name)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py:382, in CDLL.__init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
379 self._FuncPtr = _FuncPtr
381 if handle is None:
--> 382     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
383 else:
384     self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(/Users/pedropestana/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/pedropestana/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file).
```

I already tried to reinstall the necessary libraries to install lightgbm but it still remains.

Answer (score 15):

> For **Linux** users, **glibc** >= 2.14 is required. Also, in some rare cases, when you hit `OSError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` error during importing LightGBM, you need to install OpenMP runtime library separately (use your package manager and search for `lib[g|i]omp` for doing this).
>
> For **macOS** (we provide wheels for 3 newest macOS versions) users:
>
> Starting from version 2.2.1, the library file in distribution wheels is built by the **Apple Clang** (Xcode_8.3.3 for versions 2.2.1 - 2.3.1, Xcode_9.4.1 for versions 2.3.2 - 3.3.2 and Xcode_10.3 from version 4.0.0) compiler. This means that you don't need to install the gcc compiler anymore. Instead of that you need to install the **OpenMP** library, which is required for running LightGBM on the system with the **Apple Clang** compiler. You can install the **OpenMP** library by the following command: `brew install libomp`.

-- [LightGBM Python-package docs](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/python-package)

tl;dr: for [mac](/questions/tagged/mac), `brew install libomp`

Comment: this is not working for me.

Comment: it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I did the same as above, but I needed to install homebrew by using the code /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

then you can install libomp (brew install libomp).

Answer (score 2):

For my Mac Ventura,

I did this to make it work:

```
# Install x86_64 version of home-brew
% cd ~/Downloads
% mkdir homebrew
% curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew 
% sudo mv homebrew /usr/local/homebrew
```

Then add this into ~/.zshrc

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Then,

```
# load the path
% source ~/.zshrc  # to export the PATH above

# Install x86_64 version of libomp at required directory in error message
% arch -x86_64 /usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew uninstall libomp # maybe needed
% arch -x86_64 /usr/local/homebrew/bin/brew install libomp
% sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/
% sudo ln -s /usr/local/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I didn't need to reinstall Brew. Installing using the x86_64 commands was all I needed - m1 Ventura.

Comment: sadly I needed to install homebrew again as it would later throw error as architecture incompatible

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the easy fix for me was to install lightgbm via conda instead of pip: `conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm`

I think the solution via brew also works, but only if homebrew is installed in /usr/local on a Mac. For me, homebrew was installed in /opt/homebrew, and for that reason I couldn't install libomp correctly via brew. With conda, everything worked fine for me.